# How to use the NiFi process session migrate function?

Tags: java, session, apache-nifi

I am trying to output flow files while reading a flow file. (It outputs as soon as it finishes reading part of the file rather than the whole file)

However, it seems that the ProcessSession requires all flow files to be committed before a destination processor can read it. Otherwise there is the option of migrating it to another processor.

How do I use the migrate function? More specifically, where do I get the “newOwner” value?

Or if anyone has any ideas for my original problem?

Here is the ProcessSession code:
[github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.java](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.java)

I would very much appreciate any example processor code which uses migrate.

Answer (score 0):

check the [AbstractProcessor](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/AbstractProcessor.java) source

you could override the method

```
public final void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, 
                            final ProcessSessionFactory sessionFactory)
```

store sessionFactory link and when you need new session to be created:

```
ProcessSession newSession = sessionFactory.createSession();
```

as an example check the processor [MergeContent](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/MergeContent.java) that uses [Bin](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-extension-utils/nifi-processor-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/util/bin/Bin.java) that calls `session.migrate` ...